# Soundcloud SDK for Android

Tags: android, soundcloud

May I know, is it possible to use Soundcloud SDK with Android SDK ?

If it is, does anyone know how to use Soundcloud SDK with an Android project ?
Any sample projects or guideline links will be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is [SoundCloud Java Library](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) available, so it seems to be practical to use SoundCloud with android.

It also contains some example code.